# Elements getting located on the webpage but not through WebDriver

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am automating a simple scenario on facebook wherein I log into my account. CLick on the Friend requests icon, and get all the friend requests listed on the console. My code snippet is as below-
The Element which I am trying to locate have the xpath as - //*[@class='clearfix ruUserBox _3-z']/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a"  . If I type the above in the Firepath console  it locates all the elements. But In the code when I am trying to store these elements in a List it looks like it is not working. The console is left blank. One thing to note here is that className of these ELements is the same but id s are different. Still the firebug located all the elements correctly in the DOM,but during program execution the same doesn work. Pl help.

public class sample {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
     driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
      driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");//use personal or test id
      driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("xyz");//use personal or test password
      driver.findElement(By.id("loginbutton")).click();
      Thread.sleep(3000L);
      WebElement friend_requests_icon = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("fbRequestsJewel")));
      friend_requests_icon.click();
      driver.findElement(By.linkText("See All")).click();
      List<WebElement> friendList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='clearfix ruUserBox     _3-z']/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a"));
      Thread.sleep(3000L);
      for(int i=0;i<friendList.size();i++){
          System.out.println(friendList.get(i).getText());

      }
}
```

Comment: In firebug, when you try to locate the element did you verified the number of elements at the bottom. does your expected count and actual count of number of friend requests match at that time. i suspect there are other elements to which are getting located with the same xpath.

Comment: Yes it gives the exact number of matching nodes as the number of friend requests.. Did you try it out ? are you also getting the same error?